# Tikzpicture laid over text

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I am plotting a tikzpicture with the following code

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[hide axis]
    \plot[name path=A, very thick,samples=201,domain=8/11:1.48, color=blue] {x};
    \plot[name path=B,very thick,samples=200,domain=0.81:8/11, color=blue]{12*x-8};
    \plot[name path=C,very thick,samples=200,domain=0.81:1.48, color=blue]{-.35*x+2};
    \addplot[fill=blue,opacity=.1] fill between [of=A and B, soft clip={domain=.81:1.48}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However this produces a plot which is placed over the text, although I simply want the figure below, or on top, whatever [htpb] decides.

[image]

I have no idea what I am missing. I actually produced other plots in essentially the same way, where this problem is not appearing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Still, this is a very odd way of drawing a filled triangle where only one line of code could have done the same...

Comment: @SebGlav haha that's true, but the plot is actually a bit more sophisticated and I need the linear equations which define the edges of the triangle. I just got rid of most of the code to provide a mwe.

Comment: That makes sense ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply add `clip bounding box=default tikz` option to your `axis` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[hide axis, clip bounding box=default tikz]
    \plot[name path=A, very thick,samples=201,domain=8/11:1.48, color=blue] {x};
    \plot[name path=B,very thick,samples=200,domain=0.81:8/11, color=blue]{12*x-8};
    \plot[name path=C,very thick,samples=200,domain=0.81:1.48, color=blue]{-.35*x+2};
    \addplot[fill=blue,opacity=.1] fill between [of=A and B, soft clip={domain=.81:1.48}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Read more about the way `hide axis` affect the bounding box in **4.20.2 Clipping** section of the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf).

[image]